# Manipulating/Clearing Variables via Lists: Mathematica

Tags: string, list, variables, scope, wolfram-mathematica

My problem (in **Mathematica**) is referring to variables given in a particular array and manipulating them in the following manner (as an example):

**Inputs**: vars={x,y,z}, system=some ODE like x^2+3*x*y+...etc
(note that I haven't actually created variables x y and z)

**Aim**:

To assign values to the variables in the list "var" with the intention of inputting these values into the system of ODEs. Then, once I am done, clear the values of the variables in the array vars so that it is in its original form {x,y,z} (and not something like {x,1,3} where y=1 and z=3). I want to do this by referring to the positional elements of vars (I aim not to know that x, y and z are the actual variables).

The reason why: I am trying to write a program that can have any number of variables and ODEs as defined by the user. Since the number of variables and the actual letters used for them are unknown, it is necessary to perform manipulations with the array itself.

**Attempt:**

A fixed number of variables is easy. For the arbitrary case, I have tried modules and blocks, but with no success. Consider the following code:

`Clear[x,y,z,vars,svars]`

`vars={x,y,z}`

`svars=Map[ToString,vars]`

`Module[{vars=vars,svars=svars},`

`Symbol[svars[[1]]]//Evaluate=1`

`]`

then vars={1,y,z} and not {x,y,z} after running this. I have done functional programming with lists, atoms etc. Thus is makes sense to me that vars is changed afterwards, because I have changed x and not vars. However, I cannot get "x" in the list of variables to remain local. Of course I could put in "x" itself, but that is particular to this specific case. I would prefer to put something like:

`Clear[x,y,z,vars,svars]`

`vars={x,y,z}`

`svars=Map[ToString,vars]`

`Module[{vars=vars,svars=svars, vars[[1]]},`

`Symbol[svars[[1]]]//Evaluate=1`

`]`

which of course doesn't work because vars[[1]] is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol.

**Other possibilities:** 
I found a function

`assignToName[name_String, value_] :=`
`ToExpression[name, InputForm, Function[var, var = value, HoldAll]]`

which looked promising. Basically name_String is the name of the variable and value is its new value. I attempted to do:

`vars={x,y,z}`
`svars=Map[ToString,vars]`
`vars[[1]]=//Evaluate=1`
`assignToName[svars[[1]],svars[[1]]]`

but then something like`D[x^2, vars[[1]]]`  doesn't work (x is not a valid variable).

If I am missing something, or if perhaps I am going down the wrong path, I'm open to trying other things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say that I followed your train(s) of thought very well, so these are fragments which might help you to answer your own questions than a coherent and fully-formed answer.  But to answer your final 'question', I think you may be going down some wrong path(s).

In passing, note that evaluating the expression

```
vars = {x,y,z}
```

does in fact define those three variables though it doesn't define any rewrite rules (such as values) for them.

Given a polynomial `poly` you can extract the variables in it with the function `Variables[poly]` so something like

```
Variables[x^2+3*x*y]
```

should return

```
{x,y}
```

Note that I write 'should' rather than does because I don't have Mathematica on this machine so my syntax may be a bit wonky.  Note also that your example ODE is nothing of the sort but it strikes me that you can probably write a wrapper to manipulate an ODE into a form from which `Variables` can extract the variables.  Mathematica offers a lot of other functions for picking expressions apart and re-assembling them, follow the trails from `Variables`.  It often allows the use of functions defined on `Lists` on expressions with other heads too so it's always worth experimenting a bit.

There are a couple of widely applicable ways to avoid setting values of variables in Mathematica.  For instance, you could write

```
x^2+3*x*y/.{x->2,y->3}
```

which will evaluate to

```
22
```

but not set values for `x` and `y`.  This is a very simple example of using (sets of) replacement rules for temporary assignment of values to variables

The other way to avoid setting values for variables is to define functions using `Modules` or `Blocks` both of which define their own contexts. The documentation will tell you all about these two and the differences between them.

I can't help thinking that all your clever tricks using `Symbol`, `ToExpression` and `ToString` are a bit beside the point.  Spend some time familiarising yourself with Mathematica's in-built functionality before going further down that route, you may well find you don't need to.

Finally, writing, in any language, expressions such as

```
vars=vars,svars=svars
```

will lead to madness.  It may be syntactically correct, you may even be able to decrypt the semantics when you first write code like that, but in a week's time you will curse your younger self for writing it.